# Create a hybrid .iso directly from a Mac/PC hybrid CD?

Tags: mac, iso-image, disk-image, hfs+, hfs

I have several dozen hybrid Mac/PC CDs and would like to create .iso images of them. The Mac partitions are HFS and HFS+, the PC partitions are ISO9660.

Currently, I copy the Mac content after mounting the default HFS partition. Then I manually mount the ISO partition using `mount_cd9660` and so forth via the Terminal, and copying the PC content separately.

I can then create a new hybrid .iso using the two chunks of copied content, but would love to find a way to simply copy the original CDs directly to .iso images while maintain the hybrid formatting.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share my answer. I don't know if this works on OLD Macs, but on current M1 Macs, I was able to nab the entire Mac/PC hybrid ISO as one combined ISO through the Terminal. So, of course, on current macOSes, Apple_HFS isn't even allowed to mount. So, when I insert in the CD, I just ignore when it tells me the disk can't be initialized.

To figure out the ID of my mounted disc, in Terminal, I type in:

```
diskutil list
```

If someone's planning on trying this out on a Mac that still recognizes Apple_HFS, you'll probably have to do this un-mounting step...

```
sudo umount /dev/disk[INSERT YOUR CORRESPONDING NUMBER HERE]
```

... Then, in the list that pops up, look for whichever disk has "Apple_HFS" listed as one of its parts. Then, you're going to type in:

```
sudo cp /dev/disk[INSERT YOUR CORRESPONDING NUMBER HERE]s1 [INSERT OUTPUT NAME HERE].iso
```

If it's a disc with an extra *Audio CD* partition, that can't be contained in an ISO-- you'll have to bin/cue it with something like cdrdao, coupled with toc2cue to fix the cue format afterwards (rename the cue to a .toc, then have it convert that to a .cue).

It seemed too simple, but after it all transferred, I booted it successfully in both a Windows VM and a Mac OS 9 VM, with only the corresponding files showing in each! Only took me over a decade to get this right, hahaha. >_O

To eject on an M1 Mac (since, you know, there's no disk mounted to eject), go into Disk Utility, right-click your CD drive and hit Eject. (You can also eject in Terminal with a command like "drutil tray eject [INSERT NUMBER HERE]" -- you can figure out which tray you're ejecting with "drutil list", just like with diskutil.) Even after ejecting/unmounting, sometimes, a little phantom disk will stay behind in the diskutil list. This will affect many of the VMs you might be trying to use like SheepShaver & BasiliskII. That will also need to be ejected in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but I think this is what you're looking for…

Copied verbatim from Apple KB: [Create a disk image using Disk Utility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/dskutl11888/mac)

> **Create a disk image from a folder or connected device**
>
> You can create a disk image that contains the contents of a folder or
>   connected device, such as a USB device. This method doesn’t copy a
>   device’s free space to the disk image. For example, if a USB device or
>   volume is 80GB with 10GB of data, the disk image will be 10GB in size
>   and include only data, not free space. You can then restore that disk
>   image to another volume.
>
> 1. In the Disk Utility app  on your Mac, choose File > New Image, then choose Image from Folder.
> 2. Select the folder or connected device in the dialogue that appears, then click Open.
> 3. Enter a filename for the disk image, add tags if necessary, then choose where to save it. This is the name that appears in the Finder,
>      where you save the disk image file before opening it.
> 4. To encrypt the disk image, click the Encryption pop-up menu, then choose an encryption option.
> 5. Click the Image Format pop-up menu, then choose an option:
>
>    - Read-only: The disk image can’t be written to, and is quicker to create and open.
>    - Compressed: Compresses data, so the disk image is smaller than the original data. The disk image is read-only.
>    - Read/write: Allows you to add files to the disk image after it’s created. DVD/CD master: Can be used with third-party apps. It includes
>        a copy of all sectors of the disk image, whether they’re used or not.
>        When you use a master disk image to create other DVDs or CDs, all data
>        is copied exactly.
>    - Hybrid image (HFS+/ISO/UDF): This disk image is a combination of disk image formats and can be used with different file system
>        standards, such as HFS, ISO and UDF.
> 6. Click Save, then click Done.
>      Disk Utility creates the disk image file where you saved it in the Finder and mounts its disk icon on your
>      desktop and in the Finder sidebar.

Comment: I have verified that this method works … partially.

The .dmg image that gets created contains both the contents of the HFS partition and the ISO partition from the source CD. The HFS partition mounts by default on the Mac, but when you mount the ISO partition, it includes those same Mac files and folders alongside the PC formatted content.

It’s unfortunate that the Mac content ends up sitting amidst the PC content, as it’s basically a duplicated set of files, but with all of the Mac-specific resources and file attribute information stripped away.

So, we’re almost there, but not quite.

Comment: Sorry it didn't quite work. tbh it's so long since I had to do anything like this my memory is hazy. I used to use Roxio Toast for many years, for all kinds of optical disk  twiddling, but it might be a bit expensive if you only need it for one trick.

Comment: Looking into this a bit further, it seems like [Toast](https://www.roxio.com/en/products/toast/) might be the best solution. It can apparently copy hybrid discs verbatim. Likely worth it for me, as I have dozens of discs to image.